# Checking for multiple image extensions?

Tags: php

I would like to format a directory of images by removing the file extensions. I'm using `basename()` to do so but I can only check for one suffix. How can I also check for `.png` & `.jpeg` with my code below? Is it possible to use a regex here?

```
function sanitize_items($value) {
    $base = basename(strtolower($value), '.jpg');
    $temp = explode('-', $base);
    return $temp[0];
}

foreach ($list[1] as $f) {
    $file_sanitized[sanitize_items($f)] = $f;
}
```

Comment: `if (preg_match('#\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp)$#i', $filePath)) { //Yay }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead:

```
$temp = explode('-', pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
return strtolower($temp[0]);
```

Comment: @user2930185: I updated the answer to include the `explode` -- but what exactly is not working? And what exactly do you mean "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easy - use glob():

```
$pictures = glob("/your/path/*{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

$result = array();
foreach ($pictures as $pic) {
    $tmp = pathinfo($pic);
    $result[] = $tmp['filename'];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `pathinfo()`

```
$ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
return str_replace('.'.$ext, '', $value);
```